# PyQGIS algorithm qgis:joinattributesbynearest not found

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, algorithm

After re-installing Windows and QGIS 3.14 it seems like some PyQGIS algorithms are not working. For example:

```py
processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbynearest", options)
```

gives

`core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm qgis:joinattributesbynearest not found`

I checked the algorithm ID in the [latest docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html), and it is correct.

For troubleshooting, I created a list of all available algorithms using

```py
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print(alg.id(), "->", alg.displayName())
```

This results in quite a long file to share here but nowhere in the file I can find the algorithm name or identifier.

Note that the algorithm is available via the Processing Toolbox in the GUI, so I wonder where the PyQGIS version is hiding.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
Turned out that the algorithm_id from documentation is not correct, as hovering over the algorithm name in the QGIS Processing Toolbox revealed that the algorithm is named: 'native:joinbynearest'. Didn't know that trick before so I always looked up the algorithm_id in the online documentation.